# Java itself changes the size of the character

Tags: java, uppercase

I am a beginner in java
While doing tasks
I encountered a problem
The code itself changes in the word riverrrrr r small to R large

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {
    static String toCamelCase(String s) {
        if (s.contains("_")) {
            s = s.replace("_", "-");
        }
        String[] list = s.split("-");
        String nowa = "";
        String result = "";
        String result1 = "";
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(list[0].charAt(0))) {
                nowa = list[i].replace(list[i].charAt(0), list[i].toUpperCase().charAt(0));
                result += nowa;
                System.out.println(nowa);
                result1 = result;
            }
            if (Character.isLowerCase(list[0].charAt(0))) {
                nowa = list[i].replace(list[i].charAt(0), list[i].toUpperCase().charAt(0));
                result += nowa;
                result1 = result.replace(result.charAt(0), result.toLowerCase().charAt(0));
            }
        }
        return result1;
    }
}
```

Why change riverrrrr on RiverRRRRR ? I want only Riverrrrr, why rrrrr is uppercase?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm09d.png)

Comment: note that code snippets are not for java code, it's intended for HTML, CSS and Javascript. anyway in regard to your task, it seems you're over complicating this here. if you only want to uppercase the first letter you don't need to loop. further, what exactly are you trying to achieve, there might be an easier way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

**public String replace(char oldChar,char newChar)** It will replace all occurrence of matched char

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

Use `replaceFirst()`

```
public String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)
```

> Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

**In your code** change this to

```
nowa = list[i].replace(list[i].charAt(0), list[i].toUpperCase().charAt(0));
```

This

```
nowa = list[i].replaceFirst(String.valueOf(list[i].charAt(0)), String.valueOf(list[i].toUpperCase().charAt(0)));
```

**Input :** `"lake_riverrrr"`

**Output :** `lakeRiverrrr`

Answer (score 2):

Because in your `if` statements you have:

```
nowa = list[i].replace(list[i].charAt(0), list[i].toUpperCase().charAt(0));
```

Which replaces every instance of the first char with the upper case version.

If you only want to capitalize the first letter, then just take the `substring` of the first letter, use `toUpperCase()` on that and add it to the `substring` of the rest of the word. Alternatively you can use `replaceFirst` to only replace the first letter